# Using fdlibm library in C

Tags: c

I am trying to use the fdlibm library in C to compute sin of a large number. I used the code from this link: http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/ and downloaded the folder "s_sin.c plus dependencies". When I run the c code in that folder "s_sin.c", I get the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "___ieee754_rem_pio2", referenced from:
> _sin in s_sin-a92222.o
> "___kernel_cos", referenced from:
> _sin in s_sin-a92222.o
> "___kernel_sin", referenced from:
> _sin in s_sin-a92222.o
> "_main", referenced from:
> implicit entry/start for main executable
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Here is the code that I mentioned above:

```
    /* @(#)s_sin.c 1.3 95/01/18 */
/*
 * ====================================================
 * Copyright (C) 1993 by Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *

 * Developed at SunSoft, a Sun Microsystems, Inc. business.
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
 * software is freely granted, provided that this notice 
 * is preserved.
 * ====================================================
 */

/* sin(x)
 * Return sine function of x.
 *
 * kernel function:
 *  __kernel_sin        ... sine function on [-pi/4,pi/4]
 *  __kernel_cos        ... cose function on [-pi/4,pi/4]
 *  __ieee754_rem_pio2  ... argument reduction routine
 *
 * Method.
 *      Let S,C and T denote the sin, cos and tan respectively on 
 *  [-PI/4, +PI/4]. Reduce the argument x to y1+y2 = x-k*pi/2 
 *  in [-pi/4 , +pi/4], and let n = k mod 4.
 *  We have
 *
 *          n        sin(x)      cos(x)        tan(x)
 *     ----------------------------------------------------------
 *      0          S       C         T
 *      1          C      -S        -1/T
 *      2         -S      -C         T
 *      3         -C       S        -1/T
 *     ----------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Special cases:
 *      Let trig be any of sin, cos, or tan.
 *      trig(+-INF)  is NaN, with signals;
 *      trig(NaN)    is that NaN;
 *
 * Accuracy:
 *  TRIG(x) returns trig(x) nearly rounded 
 */

#include "fdlibm.h"

#ifdef __STDC__
    double sin(double x)
#else
    double sin(x)
    double x;
#endif
{
    double y[2],z=0.0;
    int n, ix;

    /* High word of x. */
    ix = __HI(x);

    /* |x| ~< pi/4 */
    ix &= 0x7fffffff;
    if(ix <= 0x3fe921fb) return __kernel_sin(x,z,0);

    /* sin(Inf or NaN) is NaN */
    else if (ix>=0x7ff00000) return x-x;

    /* argument reduction needed */
    else {
        n = __ieee754_rem_pio2(x,y);
        switch(n&3) {
        case 0: return  __kernel_sin(y[0],y[1],1);
        case 1: return  __kernel_cos(y[0],y[1]);
        case 2: return -__kernel_sin(y[0],y[1],1);
        default:
            return -__kernel_cos(y[0],y[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are either missing a header, or you are failing to link against a needed library. Show us how you are compiling the code. What does your compile string with options look like?

Comment: Hello. I am compiling it like this: gcc s_sin.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to build `libm.a` from the `fdlibm` files. If you look at [readme](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/readme) file it explains:

```
CONFIGURE
        To build FDLIBM, edit the supplied Makefile or create
        a local Makefile by running "sh configure"
        using the supplied configure script contributed by Nelson Beebe
```

(**note:** after downloading all the files and `makefile`, you can simply type `make` and it will build `libm.a`)

This will create `libm.a` (which you can link with instead of the normal math library). After you build the library, you need only `#include "fdlibm.h"` in your source file and compile similar to:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Ofast -L./ -o test_s_sin test_s_sin.c  -lm
```

This will compile your code (named `test_s_sin.c` above) to executable.

The reason you cannot simply build `s_sin.c` with gcc is if you look in `s_sin.c`, you will find it depends on a number of additional externally defined functions from fdlibm (which in turn depend on other source file in the library). For example in `s_sin.c` you have:

```c
    /* High word of x. */
        ix = __HI(x);

    /* |x| ~< pi/4 */
        ix &= 0x7fffffff;
        if(ix <= 0x3fe921fb) return __kernel_sin(x,z,0);

    /* sin(Inf or NaN) is NaN */
        else if (ix>=0x7ff00000) return x-x;

    /* argument reduction needed */
        else {
            n = __ieee754_rem_pio2(x,y);
            switch(n&3) {
                case 0: return  __kernel_sin(y[0],y[1],1);
                case 1: return  __kernel_cos(y[0],y[1]);
                case 2: return -__kernel_sin(y[0],y[1],1);
                default:
                        return -__kernel_cos(y[0],y[1]);
            }
```

Where you have the functions or macros `__HI()`, `__kernel_sin()`, `__ieee754_rem_pio2()`, etc.. all required by `s_sin.c`. These are provided by the other sources in fdlibm, but are all meant to work together as a library rather than single source files you can cherry-pick from.